# Uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Determine whether or not the given se
ries of functions converges uniformly
on the indicated interval (set)
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1)}{(nx)^2}$ where x $\in (0,1]$

I don't know if we can apply 
can we apply the (Weierstrass M -test) because i cant find any sequence of nonegative number that is always greater than and converges , but i also don't find any epsilon for which it diverges . any hints guys

Comment: What's the definition at $$x=0$$?

Comment: sorry i meant open at zero i edited it

Comment: What can you say about $f(t) = 1/t^2$?

Comment: it's a p series that converges !

Comment: But what is the behavior nearby $0$?

Comment: it blows to infinity

Comment: You won't find divergence because it does converge pointwise. Have you considered that the partial sums factor as $\frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^2}$? This should be enough to show that it fails the Cauchy test.

Comment: Yeah, pointwise it converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{6x^2}$.